# UITableView visible cells calculated position of view after auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am using visibleCells property of UITableView. In scrollViewDidEndScrolling, I am calculating which ones are visible for user based on content offset and height of cell and after that I am just printing the position of button inside UITableViewCell. 
The issues is that the position of the button is not being calculated yet. Even if after the calculation I call cell.layoutIfNeeded(), the origin of the button is not calculated right.

Does anyone know is the cell in visibleCells already with calculated views using auto layout or it just returns cells before auto layout calculation takes place?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did eventually is calling [convertRect:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convertrect)

I passed for view nil value, so it returned correct position in the window object. I am still amazed by this magic, since position of the frame in superview is not correct and after calling the convert rect method, I get right position in the window coordinate system.